# Sort items that were added dynamically

Tags: jquery, html, sorting

I am trying to create a calendar where the user drops an item into a date box (ul). Once it is there I want them to be able to sort the items. It works but the item is not constrained to the ul. I can drag them anywhere and other items don't move. BTW the draggable item is removed and entered into the date box via ajax.

```js
jQuery('.schedule-item').draggable();

//schedule item (si) need to be draggable to date cell (dc)
jQuery("ul.box-date").droppable({

  drop: function(event, ui) {

    var dropped = jQuery(this),
      dropped_id = dropped.attr('id'),
      dragged = ui.draggable,
      dragged_id_num = dragged.attr("id").match(/\d+/g);

    jQuery.get('includes/add_to_calendar.php?id=' + dragged_id_num, function(data) {

      jQuery("#" + dropped_id).sortable();
      jQuery("#" + dropped_id).disableSelection()

      dragged.fadeOut(750, function() {
        jQuery(this).remove();
        var new_li = jQuery(data);
        dropped.append(new_li);
      })
    });
  }
});
```

The draggable element

```html
<ul>
  <li id="schedule-item=81" class="schedule-item ui-draggable ui-draggable-handle">Info</li>
</ul>
```

The calendar date box is this

```html
<div id="li-2020-03-04" class="date-cell">
  <h4>4</h4>
  <ul class="box-date ui-droppable ui-droppable-active" id="db-2020-03-04">
    <li>New Line-938</li>
    <li>New Line-443</li>
    <li>New Line-704</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: How would you like the droppable `.box-date` list to be sorted? The only quantity that seems to be available is the `innerText` property of its `<li>`s.

Comment: I want the user to sort the li by dragging them to the correct position.